# Image resize for different screens

Tags: asp.net, html, image, css, web-applications

[image: Picture showing image + button text]

Hello All,

Above picture shows a series of images and corresponding link text. Requirment is that I need to get shrink off images and also text so that they should appear in same line in different screen resolutions...

I have used vw as font specification for font resize. But unable to get image resized using the below css...

```
.bannerimage {

 max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto; 
  width: auto/9;/* ie8 */ 
  overflow:hidden;
```

}

Design code for the ribbon is as follows:

```
  <div style="padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 20px; height: 110px; width: 100%">
            <div>
                <div style="float: left">
                    <div style="float: left;">
                        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Go_to_icon.png" CssClass="footerimage" style="min-height:30px;min-width:30px" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="top: 15px; position: relative; float: left; width: 180px">
                        <div class="footerlinkdiv">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton9" runat="server" CssClass="footerlink" Text="Go To Administration Page" Style="text-align: start"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footerseprator">
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div style="float: left">
                    <div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton8" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Go_to_icon.png" CssClass="footerimage" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="top: 15px; position: relative; float: left; width: 180px">
                        <div class="footerlinkdiv">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton10" runat="server" CssClass="footerlink" Text="Go To Authorize US Partners" Style="text-align: start"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footerseprator">
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div style="float: left">
                    <div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton9" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Go_to_icon.png" CssClass="footerimage" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="top: 15px; position: relative; float: left; width: 180px">
                        <div class="footerlinkdiv">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton11" runat="server" CssClass="footerlink" Text="Go To Authorize Canada Partners" Style="text-align: start"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footerseprator">
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div style="float: left">
                    <div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton10" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Go_to_icon.png" CssClass="footerimage" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="top: 15px; position: relative; float: left; width: 180px">
                        <div class="footerlinkdiv">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton13" runat="server" CssClass="footerlink" Text="Go To Authorize Distributor Page" Style="text-align: start"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>




                </div>

            </div>

        </div>





  tried a lot.. Could some one plz help me with css of the same for below ribbon
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to resize the text without a jquery library or css media queries. But you can resize the images by giving it some value for height or width like so:

```
.bannerimage {
max-width: 100%; 
height: auto; 
width: 10%;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Tried with the above, but could not still see the shrink of image.